# Split txt file with bat every x pipes

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, cmd, split

I have a txt file with the following type of string:

A|B|B|CC|R|TRR|Y|D|S|S|S|G|Q|G|...

There is someone that can help me to create a .bat file that take this file and create a new one with the following result?

A|B|B|CC|

R|TRR|Y|D|

S|S|S|G|

In other words I need to split the string every 4 | going in a new line every 4th pipe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted a script for you to use from [here](https://www.administrator.de/frage/zeilenumbruch-20-zeichen-textdatei-als-batch-win2k-79271.html).

It adds a word-wrap every 8 symbols and saves it to a new file.

```
@echo off & setlocal 
set "in=C:\insert.txt" 
set "out=C:\output.txt" 

set S8=%temp%\Split8.vbs 
echo Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"):Text=fso.OpenTextFile("%in%",1).ReadAll>%S8% 
echo Set out=fso.OpenTextFile("%out%",2,True):For i=1 To Len(Text) Step 8:out.WriteLine Mid(Text,i,8):Next:out.Close>>%S8% 
cscript //nologo %S8% 
del %S8%
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  your script works fine, but I wasn't clear in my first request, the field between 2 pipes can be more than 1 char, for example like the following one   
A|A|A|A|A|B|B|B|B|B|X|X|XSFGS|DEDS|e|X|X|XSFGS|DEDS|B|B|B|B|X|X|XSFGS|DE|we|

In this case the output of your script is 
A|A|A|A|
A|B|B|B|
B|B|X|X|
XSFGS|
DEDS|e

Comment: is it necessary to keep the whitespaces? Your task is also easy and fast done in Notepad++

Comment: The output should be a new file with this 
A|A|A|A|
A|B|B|B|
B|B|X|X|
XSFGS|DEDS|e|X|
X|XSFGS|DEDS|B|
B|B|B|‌​X|
X|XSFGS|DE|we|

A new line every 4 pipes

Comment: I have edited the example on my first request.

Comment: oh ok, the new conditions need an more advanced script. I am try to fiddle it out, later.

Comment: Thanks so much Evo, I'm sorry but I'm not confident with bat, I thougt that a way can be this:
1 - Split the string every pipe in a new line
2 - Aggregate in one line every 4 lines

what do you think about it?